# Jupyter lab: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte while launching

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have been using `Jupiter lab` for quite some time now. However from today, whenever I try to launch Jupiter lab it's giving me this error.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 12801: character maps to

What can be the solution for this?

On the other hand, Jupiter notebook is working fine.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: At the Anaconda prompt, please do `conda update --all` and then see if the issue persists.

Comment: Also, do not post images of errors. **[No Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)** of code or data. Always provide a [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).